# Center text on a bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to draw a text on the center of a bitmap however I can't do it even though I used align.center. The code is:

```
public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext, String gText) {
    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap bitmap = 
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.blank_marker);

    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
            bitmap.getConfig();
    // set default bitmap config if none
    if(bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }
    // resource bitmaps are imutable, 
    // so we need to convert it to mutable one
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // new antialised Paint
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // text color - #3D3D3D
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
    // text size in pixels
    paint.setTextSize((int) (25 * scale));
    // text shadow
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    // draw text to the Canvas center
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2; 

    canvas.drawText(gText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove this  paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER); and replace this canvas.drawText(gText, x * scale, y * scale, paint); by this canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint); hope this will help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a lot more straightforward than you think.

Draw the text at half the `Bitmap`'s width and height (center point) in combination with `Paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)`.

The alignment property will take care of the rest.

Comment: This only centers text horizontally, but not vertically

Answer (score 3):

I guess none of the answers given above are good enough so I post my answer. Try it out guys, it will work on all devices and is not complex at all:

```
    String text = "Text"; //your string
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    paint.setTextSize(30);

    // draw text to the Canvas center
    Rect boundsText = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), boundsText);
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - boundsText.width()) / 2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + boundsText.height()) / 2;

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but it won't work for "i", "1", ".", ... - these will be more on the left and will fail miserably on "-" (will be slightly on the left and way above the middle). Try using 
canvas.drawText(text, x - bounds.left, y - bounds.bottom, paint); then text will be really in the middle.

Comment: Passing x and y into the drawText method is the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where is the text drawing? The issue might be since you changed the text align to Align.CENTER. Your code calculating x and y assumes the text rendering is using Align.LEFT, I believe.

Either use setTextAlign(Align.CENTER) and render at the actual bitmap center, or use setTextAlign(Align.LEFT) and use the current x and y calculations you are using.